# is there a way to put Tkinter menu to final project?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am creating a game for my exam project and am struggling to bring together my code and Tkinter menu.

I have a project called 'Arcade Final' which shows all the games a user can play. I import these games into my final code and call them after the relevant button is pressed.

How do I import the Tkinter code without having it in a white box like this, but just display the menu at the top?

[the current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTQq9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probable reason for your problem is you are calling `Tk()` in the sub-files, which calls the white box which is known as root window.

You can solve this by **Returning a Frame containing all widget,** and then add menu bar in the main file.

Example:

- For the file with games:

```
# test.py
from tkinter import Frame,Label
def a(root):
    a=Frame(root)
    b=Label(a,text="Hello!")
    b.pack()
    a.pack()
    return a
```

- For main file:

```
import tkinter as tk
a1=tk.Tk()
mb=  Menubutton ( a1, text="condiments", relief=RAISED )
mb.pack()
mb.menu =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"] =  mb.menu

mayoVar = IntVar()
ketchVar = IntVar()

mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="mayo",
                          variable=mayoVar )
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="ketchup",
                          variable=ketchVar )
a(a1)
a1.mainloop()
```

Comment: @SoniaK , Glad could help you, by pressing the tick button on an answer you can accept it if it solves your problem

Comment: This is amazing! Could you show me how it would look if I were to create a menu function for an exit/pause button for example? Thank you very much!

Comment: @SoniaK , you directly add menu bar into `a1` of main file. See this for details https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menubutton.htm